# Android phone hardware backbutton not firing "backbutton" event, sometimes

Tags: jquery, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am working on a phonegap (version 6+) based hybrid app. I recently noticed that on pressing the android mobile hardware back button, the phonegap `"backbutton"` event is not fired under the following circusmstances:

1. **input or textarea element is in focus and soft keyboard is up:**
   In this case the hardware back button closes the soft keyboard, but neither the element looses focus nor is the `"backbutton"` event fired
2. **select element is open**, In this case the hardware back button causes the select element to close, but the `"backbutton"` event is not fired and the select element does not trigger a `blur` or `focusout` event

On googling i can see that this seems to be a known issue, but, my question is: There is a workaround for the first case where i can listen to the window `resize` event. But for the second case i.e. the select element close, I am not sure how to capture that event? `blur` and `focusout` don't work. Is there any workaround or solution to this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Akis i want to show an element when the select element looses focus

Answer (score 1):

If you want a workaround solution for this then you can set function to check on click if select box is open or close and then if its open false set variable to true and closed then false like below.

```
//set variable global
var clickedDropdown;

$("select").bind("click", function () {
    var clickedDropdown = $(this);

    if (clickedDropdown.data('open') == false) {
        clickedDropdown.data('open', true);
        console.log(this.name + "   open");
        //Your code goes here
    } else {
        clickedDropdown.data('open', false);
        console.log(this.name + "   closed");
        //Your code goes here
    }
});
```

**Updated**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e){
            if (clickedDropdown.data('open') == true) {
                 $( "select" ).trigger( "click" );
                //or
                //You can set blur or focusout event if dropdown already open
            } else {
                //You can set another function for backbutton pressed event
            }
        });
    },500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working in my scenario, because the select elements are native android simulated with JQM. So the select element options are opened with a click, but closed with the mobile phone backbutton. So I guess the click event is not being fired when the backbutton is pressed.

Comment: Thanks again, I will try this out and get back to you.

Comment: This did not work, because this code works with the backbutton event, but the issue is that the backbutton is not being fired in this case, as I have explained in the question. What I need is a workaround to detect that the backbutton is being fired while select element is open.

Comment: to give more context i was able to detect backbutton fired while soft keyboard is open. because when the backbutton is fired the soft keyboard closes and the window resizes.